# Ionic 3 : Upgrade fontawesome 4 to 5

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, ionic3, font-awesome

I build an app in Ionic 3 and currently I use fontawesome 4 to display some icons like this :

```
<i class="fa fa-close" style="color : darkgray"></i>
```

But know, I want to upgrade my version to 5. I want to keep use of  balise.

But I can't find how to upgrade the version ...

I tried this with npm : https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/use-with-node-js

I run npm commands and write this in my index.html

```
<script>
      const fontawesome = require('@fortawesome/fontawesome')
      const faFlag = require('@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid/faFlag')
      const faSquare = require('@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid/faSquare')

      fontawesome.icon(faFlag).abstract[0]
  </script>
```

I have this error :

```
require.js:7 Uncaught Error: Module name "@fortawesome/fontawesome" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
    at F (require.js:7)
    at Object.m [as require] (require.js:26)
    at requirejs (require.js:32)
    at (index):40
```

Somebody please can explain me what is the best way to install fontawesome 5 with Ionic 3 ?